# Question about Most Appropriate Analysis for Repeated Measures (heart function)?

Tags: repeated-measures, medicine

More of a general question.

I have a dataset in which each subject undergoes a specific intervention. I have their pre-intervention heart function and then their 6-month and 12-month post-intervention heart function. I want to answer two questions with this data:

1. Does heart function following the intervention change over time? Or is it the same after 12-months?
2. Are there other variables associated with changes in heart function?

In reading up on it, seemingly some sort of repeated measures analysis would be the most appropriate. I do have missing data, so I think repeated measures ANOVA would be inappropriate. In my readings, I did come across mixed model analysis? Would this be appropriate? Additionally, if anyone has some resources on how to do this in R, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Sample size? How do you measure heart function?

Comment: about 500 subjects, ejection fraction

Comment: Please add new info as an edit to the post, not only as comments! Not everybody reads comments ...